# Modal window closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I can't process the closing of the modal window, it won't close and then gives me an error, please help me.

```js
let modalSubmitInteraction;

try {
    modalSubmitInteraction = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
        filter: (i) => {
            console.log("Waiting for modal submission");
            console.log(i.fields);
            return true;
        },
        time: 30000,
    });
} catch (error) {
    if (error.code === "InteractionCollectorError") {
        if (error.message === "timeout") {
            // If the user closed the modal, just end the execution
            console.log("User closed the modal window");
            return;
        } else {
            return interaction.followUp({
                content: "The modal submission wait time has expired. Please try again.",
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Unexpected error while waiting for modal:", error);
    }
}
```

For me, if it doesn’t close, it issues a command twice and an error if another modal window is used later, I need to process the code so that if I accidentally close the modal window, then it closes so that there is no duplication of the command

Comment: Use a custom random ID for the modal, and check this ID in the filter function. It will make each modal unique.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your advice and it worked, I appreciate you

Comment: _"it won't close and then gives me an error"_ What's the error?